# Xamarin PCL project - Create LaunchScreen.storyboard with image as background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a LaunchScreen.storyboard according to this guide [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/...](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/) and instead of using a solid color as background I am placing an Image View which I need it to fill the screen according to the device that the app runs. Still I cant seem to be able to place any width and height constraints relative to the size of the screen and not as constant values. I am working on VS 2017 in a Windows machine and use a MacBook for the iOS testing part of the app. Thanks

Comment: No need to set width or height , just need to set left, top, right, bottom margin  with superview.

Comment: I’ve already tried that but it seems to add only two constraints at a time with the super view (top & left or top & right or bottom and left etc). I think that the visual studio designer is a little slow, buggy and hard to work on.